# Is there a bijection there?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, duality-theorems

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $T$ a subset of $X^{\prime} = \mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R})$. Then define the set:
$$^{\circ}T\ :=\ \{\;x\in X\ :\ F(x)=0,\ \forall\ F\in T\;\}.$$
(When) Is possible the get a bijection $G\in\mathcal{L}(T,\;^{\circ}T)$? Where
$$\mathcal{L}(X,Y)\ =\ \{F:X\rightarrow Y\ \mbox{ such that }
 F \mbox{ is linear and bounded}\}.$$

Thanx so much in advance.

Comment: Is there any motivation for this question? Because it fails in most simple cases like in $\mathbb{R}^2$ when $T$ consists of the single functional $F(x_1,x_2)=x_1$. Then ${}^\circ T = {0}\times\mathbb{R}$ cannot be isomorphic to a single element.

Comment: Well, it is a *Galois connection*, and as such, there is a bijection, but between the set of *closed* subsets on both sides, which are now certainly some *subspaces*.

Comment: The motivation is that I need to proved that there's a bijection from $^{\circ}((X/M)^{\prime})$ to $^{\circ}(M^{\circ})$. But I only could found a bijection from $M^{\circ}$ to $(X/M)^{\prime}$. So, in order to do that, I thought to find bijections from $^{\circ}(M^{\circ})$ to $M^{\circ}$ and from $^{\circ}((X/M)^{\prime})$ to $(X/M)^{\prime}$.

Comment: I think, there's nothing more here than $(X/M)'\cong M^\circ$.
If we interpret ${}^\circ((X/M)')$ as a subset of $X/M$, then, I guess, it will be $0$. On the other hand, if we want to interpret ${}^\circ((X/M)')$ as a subset of $X$, then we have to *identify* $(X/M)'$ with $M^\circ$.